# vsphere client connection refused

Tags: vmware, esxi, vcenter

I have  setup an ESXI server in my vmware workstation test environment. I can access it fine withouth any problems.

I also have added an Vcenter server appliance server in vmware workstation. Installation went fine but as soon as I type in the ip address in my browser I get this site cant be reached. connection refused.

This are the addresses I have tried:

- 10.0.0.1:9443
- 10.0.0.1:9433/vsphere-client
- 10.0.0.1
- https://10.0.0.1:9433/vsphere-client
- https://10.0.0.1:9433
- http://10.0.0.1:9433/vsphere-client
- http://10.0.0.1:9433

None of them work.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you able to see the vCenter landing page at https://10.0.0.1/ ? Note: be specific about putting the _https_ schema.

Comment: I just realized the port you're trying is 9433 while the right one is 9443